# What does "mean" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> In California, wildfires are raging again and strong winds and dry
>   forests **mean** that the flames spread over 177 kilometres and destroy
>   thousands of buildings.

I don't understand why '*mean*' is put there. 
Does '*mean*' contain the meaning of like '*result*'? 
If so, Why did it use present tense, '*mean*' instead of past tense 'meant'?

Comment: Maybe post this ELL(learners)? https://youtu.be/-sr3QlUgfio?t=11

Comment: Hello, Young, and welcome to EL&U. Please check in a [general reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mean) before asking single word meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the present tense because the whole sentence is in the present tense: "...are raging... mean ... spread [are spreading]... destroy [{are} destroying]..."

" Mean" is used because the strong winds and dry forests are having a direct effect on how quickly the fires are spreading.

You could replace "mean that" with "are causing":

> In California, wildfires are raging again and strong winds and dry
>   forests are causing the flames to spread over 177 kilometres and
>   destroy thousands of buildings.